# How to do RUNSTAts on a particular table in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus, database-administration

I need some idea to do my job on performing a RUNSTATS on a particular table

Comment: Question makes no sense - you don't run RUNSTATS `on a table` - it's for comparing runs of different SQL queries!

Answer (score 0):

```
exec dbms_stats.gather_table_stats (ownname => 'foo', tabname => 'bar', estimate_percent => dbms_stats.auto_sample_size, cascade => TRUE);
```